# Navigation drawer with My Account entry

Tags: navigation, android, accounts

I am adding a [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) for my Android app.

My app has a "my account" page where the user can see his account details.

My app also has 3 types of subscriptions that the user can choose from (lets say `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`).

I'd like it if I could show the user what kind of subscription he has in the nav drawer as well.

So to sum it up, I want to show 3 things in the "ACCOUNT" section of the nav drawer:

ACCOUNT:

1. User photo thumbnail (taken from Facebook when the user logged in)
2. Link to my account page
3. Subscription type indicator (`sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`)

My question is, whats the best way to arrange it ? I think that maybe the link to my account entry is unnecessary but I don't know if the users will know that clicking on the photo / subscription type will lead to the account page.

I don't have any mockup yet, but if I take the Youtube app as an example: [image]

You can see it has an `ACCOUNT` section like i'm planning to add. I want to have an image of the user there as well, and also a subscription type indicator (could be just a text line that says `sub1`). Also, I have a separate account page with more details about the account. In order to get to the account page the user needs to click something and navigate to it. I'm not sure how to tie it all together. you think it will be clear if i'd make the ubscription type indicator clickable ?

Comment: Have you got a mockup of how you've currently got it looking? It's quite a visual layout question you're asking so it'll help out if you can show what you've currently gone with.

Comment: @JonW I don't have a mockup yet, but I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly I'd say you need to rank your information in order of importance. The users name being, presumably, the most important and therefore what they need to see to tell them

a) they are logged in and

b) which account they're logged in with.

The picture is a useful visual aid to this. Once you've ascertained what is most important then you should be focusing on making that the thing that is most obvious to the user. Then I would put your subscription type underneath the user name, placing the users image next to both name and subscription level so that it doesn't take up too much space. As far as tying it all together goes if you make the entire row clickable, with it pointing to the account page and the subscription levels are explained on that page then it will be obvious enough to the user. Most of the Google apps I've come across do it that way.

[image: Example Navigation Layout]

This is how I would do it (excuse the quick and dirty mock up!). To make what the subscription is extra obvious you can always do as I have done and actually label it, this will help with confusion if you call your subscriptions things such as gold and platinum. Alternately you can go with something like "Gold Subscription" and forgo the label.

As the profile details are in a click-able list it would seem obvious that, since you can click everything else, you can click your name/image and it'll take you to your profile or account page. I've left two rows for the user name to allow for longer names and I've made it more obvious by using a slightly larger and darker coloured font.

To see how other people have tackled this problem you could visit one of these sites, they show design patterns for all sorts of things, including navigation.

[Android App Patterns Navigation Page](http://www.android-app-patterns.com/category/navigation)

[Android Interaction Design Navigation Questions](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_category/navigation)